# Sliding hover menu text toggle not fitting in

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a menu that on item hover the width of the item slides, with the background image to the right, and text appears on the left. Now when I do that, the appearing of the text is not looking good - the text is doing some jumping effect.. Can anyone help me fix this menu?

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="menu" align="center">

<a title="Passwords Management" href="admin-passwords-management.php"><li id="menu-item" class="menu-first"><p class="" style="display: none;">Passwords management</p></li></a>
        <li id="menu-item" class="website-not-active"><img src="../dashboard/images/menu2.png"></li>
        <a href="admin-facebook-management.php"><li id="menu-item" class="menu-third"><p class="" style="display: none;">Facebook apps management</p></li></a>
        <a href="admin-email-management.php"><li id="menu-item" class="menu-fourth"><p class="" style="display: none;">Email management</p></li></a>
                <a href="dashboard-billing.php"><li id="menu-item" class="menu-bill"><p class="" style="display: none;">Billing management</p></li></a>
        <a href="dashboard_client_settings.php"><li id="menu-item" class="menu-fifth"><p class="" style="display: none;">Client info</p><!--<img src="../dashboard/images/menu5.png"/>--></li></a>
    </ul>
```

and the JS:

```
$(".menu-first").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(".menu-first p").addClass("normal");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    $(".menu-first p").removeClass("normal");
    }
});

$(".menu-bill").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(".menu-bill p").addClass("normal");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    $(".menu-bill p").removeClass("normal");
    }
});

$(".menu-second").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(".menu-second p").addClass("normal");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
$(".menu-second p").fadeIn(200);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    $(".menu-second p").removeClass("normal");
$(".menu-second p").fadeOut(200);

    }
});

$(".menu-third").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(".menu-third p").addClass("normal");
    $(".menu-third p").toggle("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    $(".menu-third p").removeClass("normal");

    }
});

$(".menu-fourth").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(".menu-fourth p").addClass("normal");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    $(".menu-fourth p").removeClass("normal");

    }
});

$(".menu-fifth").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(".menu-fifth p").addClass("normal");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(".normal").toggle("fast");
    $(".menu-fifth p").removeClass("normal");

    }
 });
```

Here is a the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeBaZ/)

Comment: Try setting text-align to left in your anchors. Also your html is incorrect. ul -> a -> li is invalid.

Comment: By the way, the slide-out effect can be achieved without the use of Javascript. Here is a [proof-of-concept](http://jsbin.com/uKeXApE/3/edit). Not sure if it helps, but might be an easier to manage solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion

1. Your markup isn't semantic: it should be `ul > li > a` and not `ul > a>  li > p`.
2. My approach would be CSS only and with not so much code-bloat as I see in yours (JS, CSS and HTML wise). No need for JS to add the classes. Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/FqrAF/).
3. Note how I am using the property `hover` on `li`. This doesn't work on IE8 and below.